# Powershell - Efficient Way to Return Line Numbers from Logs

Tags: powershell

I have an extremely large log file (max 1GB) which is appended to throughout the day. There are various strings within this log which I would like to search for (that I can already achieve using `Select-String`) however I am scanning the whole file on every sweep which is inefficient and a tad unnecessary.

Ideally I want to scan only the last 5 minutes of the log for these strings on each sweep. Unfortunately not every row of the log file contains a timestamp. I initially thought of doing a wildcard `select-string` for the last 5 mins timestamps combined with the strings of interest will miss some occurrences. My only other idea at the moment is to determine the line numbers of interest, `$FromLineNumber` (5 mins before current system time) and `$ToLineNumber` (the very last line number of log file) and then only `Select-String` between those two line number ranges.

As an example, to search between line 50 and the final line of the log. I am able to return the line number of `$FromLineNumber` but I'm struggling with grabbing `$ToLineNumber` for final row of log.

Q. How do I return only the line number of the final row of a log file?

So far I have tried returning this with `Get-Content $path -tail -1` (object type linenumber) however this always returns blank values even with various switches and variations. I can only return line numbers via the `Select-String` cmdlet however I do not have a specific string to use that relates to the final row of the log. Am I misusing this cmdlet per its original design and if so...is there any other alternative  to return the last line number?

Continued...Once I have determined the line number range to search between would I isolate those rows using a Get-Content loop between
`$FromLineNumber` and `$ToLineNumber` first to filter down to this smaller selection and then pipe this into a Select-String or is there a more efficient way to achieve this? I suspect that looping through thousands of lines would be demanding on resources so I'm keen to know if there is a better way.

Comment: "Unfortunately not every row of the log file contains a timestamp" could you show us a sample of this unusual log file? To get the last line number you may have success with `Get-Content .\file.log |Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty ReadCount`, but you'll still need to figure out which line to start from

Comment: Not sure if you are intentionally tailing "minus 1"; you should be `Get-Content $path -Tail 1` (positive 1) to get the last line. And that should be fast, so if you can make a guess that your 5 minutes will be within the last 100 lines, or 1000 lines, and overshoot by a chunk of lines, that's probably still easier and quicker than any other approach. Otherwise use a file reader and step back from the end of the file, processing lines in reverse until you find a datetime before 5 minutes ago, then stop. You keep mentioning line numbers; Select-String shows them, but Get-Content can't use them

Comment: Get-Eventlog has an -after parameter that should do the trick.  If the log file has the format of an event log file, yu can and should use this cmdlet.  If it has some other form,  why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to the first question

From https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/10/09/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-count-files-words-and-lines/

> If I want to know how many lines are contained in the file, I use the Measure->Object cmdlet with the line switch. This command is shown here:

```
Get-Content C:\fso\a.txt | Measure-Object –Line
```